# Delete doc Firebase v9 React v18, indexOf issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
//Delete document
const deleteAnime = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  deleteDoc(doc(db,"Users", uid,"anime",anime.id))
  
}
```

This is the code to delete the document, where anime.id is document id

```
{anime.map(function(d, idx){
 return (<form onSubmit={deleteAnime} className={styles.card}>
        <h2 key={idx}>{idx+1}. {d.title}</h2>
          <p key={idx}>Genre: {d.genre}</p>
          <p key={idx}>Number of episodes: {d.numb}</p>
          <p key={idx}>Comment: {d.comment}</p>
          <p key={idx}>Rating: {d.rating}/10</p>
           <button key={idx} onClick={(e) => {deleteAnime(e, index)}}>Remove</button>
        </form>)})}
```

This is the return code where I attempted both in div and in form, and
receiving the error that:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Comment: What's in the deleteDoc function?

Comment: oh, actually it is nothing just this syntax as I looked to firestore guides, I thought I suppose to do something more but could not rly figure it out. The idea behind this syntax was to make delete function using deleteDoc and selecting the right document, but it cannot understand which one to delete as it does need the index (documents are the objects in the array put into one collection "anime")

Comment: I used this link as a guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data. And put the syntax into the delete function if that makes sense

Comment: I did edit the code and tried to pass index as showed above and tried to do .map(d,index) instead of .map(d,idx) as well, but it is still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is you are trying to access id from anime but it's an array not an object so i would suggest get the index of the clicked item and there will be no need to use form at all if you are not submitting any details from input.

Also you don't need to define key in every element as it will be need only on the root element of the map function

```
const deleteAnime = (item) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    deleteDoc(doc(db, "Users", uid, "anime", item.id));
}

{
    anime.map((d, idx) => {
        return (
            <div key={idx} className={styles.card}>
                <h2>{idx+1}. {d.title}</h2>
                <p>Genre: {d.genre}</p>
                <p>Number of episodes: {d.numb}</p>
                <p>Comment: {d.comment}</p>
                <p>Rating: {d.rating}/10</p>
                <button key={idx} onClick={() => deleteAnime(d)}>Remove</button>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: now i keep getting e.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: Since you're using React to attach the event handler to the DOM, the `e.preventDefault()` is not needed